# How to get the minimum and maximum values in a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
files = ['foo.0001.jpg', 'test2.0003.jpg', 'foo.0004.jpg', 'tmp.txt',
         'foo.0003.jpg', 'test2.0002.jpg', 'test2.0004.jpg', 'test.0002.jpg',
         'foo.0002.jpg', 'foo.0005.jpg', 'test.0001.jpg']
```

and I want foo.####.jpg and min, max print
           test.####.jpg and min, max print
           test2.####.jpg and min, max print

```
def get_frame_number(files):
    for c in foo:
        value = files.get(c)
        for i in value:
            num = i.split(".")[1]
            num_list.append(int(num))
        print str(min(num_list)) + "-" + str(max(num_list))
```

I have a function. but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: what isn't working? what is the `foo` that you're iterating over?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `re` to try to pull the number out of your file name. Then use this function as the `key` argument to `max` and `min` respectively.

```
import re

def get_frame_number(file):
    match = re.match(r'[\w\d]+\.(\d+)\.jpg', file)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1))
    else:
        return float('nan')

>>> max(files, key=get_frame_number)
'foo.0005.jpg'
>>> min(files, key=get_frame_number)
'foo.0001.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be using `key` arg (with [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function) of [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) built-in functions like this:

```
for fn in ('foo', 'test', 'test2'):
    fn_max = max(
        (name for name in files if name.startswith('{}.'.format(fn))),
        key=lambda name: int(name.split('.')[1]))
    fn_min = min(
        (name for name in files if name.startswith('{}.'.format(fn))),
        key=lambda name: int(name.split('.')[1]))
    print(fn, fn_max, fn_min)
```

**Output:**

```
('foo', 'foo.0005.jpg', 'foo.0001.jpg')
('test', 'test.0002.jpg', 'test.0001.jpg')
('test2', 'test2.0004.jpg', 'test2.0002.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
Why does 'test' come with 'test2' ?

Comment: Thanks buddy modern What does 'name' mean there?
Thank you very much for your kind reply to my poor English

Comment: You're welcome, name means your file name ('foo.0005.jpg', 'foo.0001.jpg', etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

foo = re.findall( r'(foo\.\d+.jpg)','|'.join( sorted(files) ) ) 
foo[0], foo[-1]
```

Output :

```
('foo.0001.jpg', 'foo.0005.jpg')
```

Similarly you can check for min, max of other files:

```
test = re.findall( r'(test\.\d+.jpg)','|'.join( sorted(files) ) )
test[0], test[-1]

test2 = re.findall( r'(test2\.\d+.jpg)','|'.join( sorted(files) ) )
test2[0], test2[-1]
```

Putting all together in one liner:

```
[ ( i[0], i[-1] ) for i in [ re.findall( r'('+ j + '\.\d+.jpg)','|'.join( sorted(files) ) ) for j in ['foo','test','test2'] ] ]
```

Output:

```
[('foo.0001.jpg', 'foo.0005.jpg'),
 ('test.0001.jpg', 'test.0002.jpg'),
 ('test2.0002.jpg', 'test2.0004.jpg')]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_frame_number(files,name):
    nums = []
    for each in files:
        parts = each.strip().split('.')
        if parts[0] == name:nums.append(int(parts[1]))
        else:print("Ignoring",each)
    return(sorted(nums)[0],sorted(nums)[-1])
```

Try this with :

```
print(get_frame_number(files,"test"))
print(get_frame_numbers(files,"test2"))
print(get_frame_numbers(files,"foo"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind reply to my poor English